# How we can solve npm install problem in laravel jetsteam?

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install

when we try to get to install npm for jetstream laravel then it show an error :

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hp/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hp\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-15T12_15_02_582Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: is `C:\Users\hp` the root of your laravel project? You need to `cd` into your laravel project before running `npm install`

Comment: i will try but it show an error